# Is there another way in PHP to use forms without using check marks or radio buttons to send data?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if there is another way in PHP or HTML to use forms without having to have check marks or radio buttons .. For example , if I just click on a link or picture , it can send data to the other PHP file according specified in form action ... I'd like to know if I can just make picture icons send data to the other php page in form action without having to use radio buttons .. but I guess if someone  only has to choose one icon from many available .. radio buttons could be the only option available or am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a bit more? There’s various input types available in HTML, so I’m not sure why you’re just thinking about checkboxes and radio inputs.

Comment: You could use a JavaScript AJAX call on clicking the image or the submit button.

Comment: Have you tried using links with query strings on the images you want to process?

Comment: @dakdad what do you exactly mean ?  can you elaborate more ?  Thanks !!!

Comment: @GuyRwayitare you could do like `<a href="/process.php?item=1&size=L"><img /></a>` and change the `item` value on each image. It would be similar to having a form method set to `GET` (depending on how you want to process it)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the `button` element.  Throw in a `type="submit"`, and you have yourself a party.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RnYeg/

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="animal" value="pig">Go</button>
</form>​
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    background: transparent url(http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-6.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
}​
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use an `img` tag:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/umuaU/2/

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="animal" value="pig"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" alt="Pig" /></button>
</form>​
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}​
```